# Multiple currency Google Currency calculator how to get the values and update the currency value

Tags: jquery

Multiple currency how to get the values from google free curency values can please help me with example program to get the values from google free currency rates updated

```
            http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?CNY
```

I have the url using this how can i get the rhl value using jquery

guys please help me out..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hourly updated: http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json

Also see:

- http://josscrowcroft.github.com/open-exchange-rates/
- http://josscrowcroft.github.com/money.js/